# Sizing Weather Widget correctly (from weatherwidget.io)

Tags: javascript, html, widget, weather, weather-api

I have configured a Widget from this Site:
https://weatherwidget.io/

And embedded it on my Website.

I put it in a DIV and it automatically gets the width right but it doesn't fill in the height.

Is there any way to change this or do I have to write my own Weather-Widget?

It looks like this:

[image: picture of my problem]

The dark grey area is the DIV and the light grey Area is the Widget.

I want to fill the whole DIV.`

EDIT:
It looks like this in the code:

```
    <div class="weatherdiv">

<a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/de/49d477d17/sankt-wendel/" data-label_1="SANKT WENDEL" data-label_2="Wetter" data-icons="Climacons Animated" data-mode="Current" data-days="3" data-theme="gray" data-basecolor="#626363" >SANKT WENDEL Wetter</a>
<script>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more context to understand better the question but if what i understood is correct and the structure is like this `<div><mywidget></mywidget></div>` you can declare the parent relative, the child absolute thanon the child you declare height 100% and it will fill up the whole space of the parent

Comment: Check my edit @Diego Gnoatto

Comment: The Weather Widget can be easily embedded in any website by just pasting the provided code in any place you would like the widget to appear.